# How to know the position of list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

```
 example: newlist = ["a,b,c","d","e","f","g"]
```

What is the position of b ?
because normally we just input newlist[0][1] to find the elements of the list

Comment: 'b' has no position since your list does not contains the element 'b'. You should be more specific about what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
search = 'b'
for i in newlist:
    for j in i:
        if j == search:
            print(str(i.index(search)) + str(newlist.index(i)))
```

That should get you: `0 1`. But this will only work if you have a 2d list.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `enumerate` for this:

```
new_list = ["a,b,c","d","e","f","g"]

for index, item in enumerate(new_list):
     print(index, item)
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 pos.py 
> 0 a,b,c
> 1 d
> 2 e
> 3 f
> 4 g
> ```

Then we can use an `if` statement to retrieve the `index`:

```
for index, item in enumerate(new_list):
    if 'b' in item:
        print(index)
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 pos.py 
> 0
> ```